# Find the "Month Name" between two dates using multiple If condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, export-to-excel

I am trying to find out the **Month Name** between two dates from 1st January to 31st December.  Currently I am using the following formula, but for some reason it is not working.

Can someone please help me?

**A1** cell is having the date in **"m/d/yyyy"** format.

Here is the formula

```
=IF(AND(A1>=1/1/2014,A1<=1/31/2014),"Jan",IF(AND(A1>=2/1/2014,A1<=2/28/2014),"Feb","Mar"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're expecting:

```
=TEXT(A1,"mmm")
```

Comment: Simply Super.  Thank you so much for your help :)